# Constructing sentences with "both"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

> A1. I was **both** unhappy with your work and your time keeping.
>
> A2. I was unhappy with **both** your work and your time keeping.
>
> B1. We were **both** unhappy with your work and your time keeping.
>
> B2. We were unhappy with **both** your work and your time keeping.

I have some doubts on the use of **both** in both sentences under the letter A and under the letter B.

Can anybody explain what are the differences and what is the "correct" way to use **both** in these cases?

Comment: I'm not sure my last sentence "Can anybody explain what are the differences and what is the "correct" way to use both in these cases?" is "standard" English. Please, feel free to modify it.

Comment: **Both** can be correctly applied to any grouping of exactly two things, and is very often incorrectly applied to groupings of three or more things. Thus it could be applied to either *we* or *your work and your time keeping* but not to other parts of this sentence, including *I*, and care should be taken to avoid placing it where ambiguity would result.

Answer (score 6):

> A1. I was both unhappy with your work and your time keeping.

A1 does not quite make sense.  As a sentence-beginning,  “I was both” leads one to expect a sentence structure of form “I was both X and Y”, where X and Y are parallel in form.  In A1, X is  “unhappy with your work” (an adverbial phrase, I think) and Y is  “your time keeping” (a noun phrase) hence X and Y are not parallel.

The other three are syntactically and semantically sound:

> A2. I was unhappy with both your work and your time keeping.

A2 means I was unhappy with your work and  I was unhappy with your time keeping.

> B1. We were both unhappy with your work and your time keeping.

B1 implies each of two parties was  unhappy with your work, and likewise unhappy with your time keeping.

> B2. We were unhappy with both your work and your time keeping.

B2 states that  some group was  unhappy with your work, and likewise unhappy with your time keeping.  In English as typically understood, it implies each of us in some group was  unhappy with your work and unhappy with your time keeping, and to some extent implies that none of us was unhappy with one item but satisfied with the other.

Answer (score 2):

A1 appears to anticipate a parallel word to 'unhappy', and, when it doesn't come, the reader feels let down. B1 suggests that 'both' goes with 'we'. Only A2 and B2 are satisfactory.

Comment: Any reason why *both* can't go with *we*?

Comment: I don't see why B1 isn't "satisfactory". Sure, it attaches "both" to "we", but so what? The word "both" is superfluous whichever word you attach it to. All it does is emphasise the plurality of either "we" or the two shortcomings. If "we" were two people who don't normally make the same judgement on such matters, B1 might be the *most* appropriate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree that **both** is superfluous in such sentences, but because so many love pleonasms, it behooves them to know where to insert them so that they do the least semantic & aural damage. Strictly speaking, B1 means **only** _the two of us were unhappy with X & Y_. Spoken in a certain way, it **might** tell the listener that "both" attaches to "X & Y" instead of to "we", but not for my inner grammarian. I agree with Barrie: "Only A2 & B2 are satisfactory". This might pass muster: B3. _We were unhappy both with your work & with your time keeping_. But it's even more verbose.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Well, yes, it's fine if that's the intended meaning, but not if the intended meaning is the same as that attempted in the other examples, which I took it to be. As for _we both_ instead of just _we_, I don't agree that it is invariably pleonastic. There will be occasions when a speaker or writer wants to emphasise the togetherness of the parties involved.

Comment: @Barrie: Well, we don't actually *know* the "intended meaning", nor does OP necessarily presuppose the same meaning has to apply to all his permutations. But I accept "superfluous" probably wasn't the best word to use there. It's *optional*, but if it *is* used, it can validly emphasise the fact of there being either two critics, or two things being criticised.